# printing same float value always

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

This program is about printing the float value `t` for different values of `i`, but it is printing same value every time.  Even though the value of `t` is changing it is always printing zero for every value of `n`.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float n;
    float sum=0,t,s=1,i;
    scanf("%f",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        t=(100/(1+2i));
        printf("\n%f",t);
    }
}
```

Input: 5

Output:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Here is that result in [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/XOIxCj).

Comment: This code won't compile with `t=(100/(1+2i));`

Comment: `1+2i` ? what is it? a complex?

Comment: with pedantic: " warning: imaginary constants are a GCC extension"

Comment: surprisingly the code _does_ compile, with gcc.

Comment: clang also compiles (and warns) about this imaginary constant thing @CareyGregory please delete your comment.

Comment: proof that it compiles: https://ideone.com/tvS1fX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
t=(100/(1+2i));
```

It seems you were intending to multiply 2 by `i`, but forget the multiplication operator `*`.  What you have instead is `2i` which is actually a complex number constant.  Note that this is not standard C but a GCC extension (`-pedantic` switch raises a warning).

Add the multiplication operator and it should work as expected.

```
t=(100/(1+2*i));
```

Comment: also maybe convert to `float` else you get integer division.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not needed since `i` is declared as `float`.

Comment: true. Can you add that this is a gcc extension and not in the C norm?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Done.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If you save the result in a `float complex` you'll get a result of 0 - 50i.  Not sure I understand the conversion.  Changing 100 to 100.0 gets the expected result of 20 - 40i.

Comment: seems that the question isn't that well received... too bad as the answer is spot on